# Linearity of logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification

Given an unknown classifier, could someone make assumptions for the linearity of this model from the fact that

$$y=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 &\;\mathrm{if}\;& p(y=1\,|\,x) \geq 0.5 \\
-1 &\;\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
?

Is that the reason we conclude logistic regression is linear?

Answer (score 7):

No, many nonlinear equations could satisfy $y=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 &\;\mathrm{if}\;& p(y=1\,|\,x) \geq 0.5 \\
-1 &\;\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.$

The logistic model can be represented as a regular linear equation except the left-hand side of the equation is transformed through a link function.  So for logistic regression, you have $\ln \left( \frac{\hat{p}}{1-\hat{p}} \right) = B_0 + B_1 X$, where $\hat{p}$ is the probability that $Y=1$.  You see the coefficients on the right-hand side ($B_0$ and $B_1$) enter the model linearly just like in simple linear regression.  The left-hand side of the equation represents the logit function of $\hat{p}$, or the log odds.  So you could could intuitively interpret that we are modeling the log odds using simple linear regression.  It is only when we back-transform the predictions that we get the nice logistic curve that does not look linear.